# Conditional entropy $H(A,B|C)$ independent of whether $p(A,B)$ factorises or not

Tags: probability, entropy, independence

I arrived at a (slightly different but hopefully more precise) reformulation of my original question shown below:

Is $H(A,B)-H(A,B|C)$ maximal for independent $A$ and $B$ in a similar sense as $H(A,B)$ alone is maximal for independent $A$ and $B$? This is asking under the constraint $H(A,B|C)=H(A|C)+H(B|C)$ and both $A$ and $B$ being dependent on $C$.

---

For random variables $A,B,C$ with $A$ and $B$ independent conditioned on $C$, while both are marginally dependent on $C$, it seems that the conditional entropy
$$H(A,B|C)=-\sum_c p(c) \sum_{a,b} p(a,b|c) \log p(a,b|c)=H(A|C)+H(B|C)$$
is independent of whether $p(a,b)$ factorises or not, i.e. of whether $A$ and $B$ are also marginally independent or not.

I'm trying to make this a more rigorous statement (something like the conditional entropy is unaffected by changing $||p_{a,b}-p_ap_b||$) as well as gain some intuition.

In particular, are there non-trivial examples where $H(A,B|C)=H(A',B'|C)$ while $A$ and $B$ are independent, $A'$ and $B'$ are dependent, both are independent conditioned on $C$, $A,A',B,B'$ are dependent on $C$, and $A\sim A'$, $B\sim B'$?
Starting with two dependent random variables, it seems mind boggling to me how one can arrive at independent variables with the same marginal distributions that leaves the conditional entropy unchanged.

Comment: "is independent of whether p(a,b)p(a,b) factorises or not."  I don't see how you get that conclusion. For a trivial counterxample, imagine $C$ is independent both from $A,B$, so that $H(A,B|C)=H(A,B)$

Comment: Maybe I'm struggling to express what exactly I mean by that. Even in your example, say $H(A,B|C)=x$ for some x, then does $x$ change if we replace $A$ and $B$ by two random variables $A'$ and $B'$ with the same conditional probabilities $p(a',b'|c)=p(a,b|c)$ and marginals $p(a')=p(a)$, $p(b')=p(b)$ but different joint probability $p(a',b')\neq p(a,b)$?

Comment: Your comment made me aware of the fact that I had missed a part from the question -- it's updated now.